# GCM Create M tables and R

Tags: gcm

I am trying to optimize GCM multiplication. This PDF explains GCM:

[The  Galois/Counter  Mode  of  Operation  (GCM)](https://luca-giuzzi.unibs.it/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/gcm-spec.pdf)

The algorithms are in section 4.1

1. In algorithm 3 I have to multiply table M [128] with the element P that represents the
   polynomial α.
   Formulas (3) and (4) appear on page 9. From what I can understand, this would be:

```
**if V127 =0 then V ← rightshift(V )
```

else
V ← rightshift(V ) ⊕ R**

The polynomial f would be 0xe1, no?

But in algorithm 3 I do not understand this: **M[i] ← M[2i] · P**. What would be the value of the element P if it corresponds to the polynomial α?

Hopefully, someone knows some code of the implementation of the tables that I can read. I have not found any code that can help me understand all of this.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57839/909) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCM cipher M0 tables : semantic questions on how to implement GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57785/gcm-cipher-m0-tables-semantic-questions-on-how-to-implement-gcm)

Comment: Please indicate if the given answer or previous Q/A's answered your question.

Comment: The document cited in the question had at least one update, formerly hosted by NIST, archived [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811123217/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-revised-spec.pdf). Some of the changes seem to be significant. It is still cited by the [current spec](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final).

Answer (score 0):

> The polynomial f would be 0xe1, no?

it is $e1 \mathbin \|0^{120}$ i.e. 0xe1000000000000000000000000000000

> What would be the value of the element P, if it corresponds to the polynomial α?

it is 2 reversed i.e. 0x40000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Could you turn the belief into reality?

Comment: @kelalaka  updated

Comment: and references?

Comment: @kelalaka The response based on my own understanding of the paper mentioned in the question. There is no other references.

Comment: if 0xE1 ($11100001_b$) represents $x^7+x^2+x+1$ then 0x40 ($01000000_b$) represents $x$